# Simple automation executing platform in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, automation

I'm building a platform like Rundeck/AWX but for server reliability testing.

People could log into a web interface upload scripts, run them on servers and get statistics on them ( failure / success).

Each script is made up of three parts, probes to check if the server is fine, methods to do stuff in the server, and rollback to reverse what we did to the server.

First we run the probes, if they past we run the methods, wait a certain time the user that created the method put, then run the probes again to check if the server self healed, if not then we run the rollbacks and probes again, then send the data to the db.

I have limited experience with programming as a job and am very unsure if what I’m doing is good let alone efficient so I would love to get some really harsh criticism.

This is the micro-service that is in charge of running the scripts of the user’s request, it gets a DNS and the fault name (fault is the whole object of probes/methods/rollbacks).

```
#injector.py

import requests
from time import sleep
import subprocess
import time
import script_manipluator as file_manipulator


class InjectionSlave():

    def __init__(self,db_api_url = "http://chaos.db.openshift:5001"):
        self.db_api_url = db_api_url


    def initiate_fault(self,dns,fault):
        return self._orchestrate_injection(dns,fault)

    def _orchestrate_injection(self,dns,fault_name):
        try :
            # Gets fault full information from db
            fault_info = self._get_fault_info(fault_name)
        except Exception as E :
            return { "exit_code":"1" ,"status": "Injector failed gathering facts" }
        try :
            # Runs the probes,methods and rollbacks by order.
            logs_object = self._run_fault(dns, fault_info)
        except :
            return { "exit_code":"1" ,"status": "Injector failed injecting fault" }
        try :
            # Sends logs to db to be stored in the "logs" collection
            db_response = self._send_result(dns,logs_object,"logs")
            return db_response
        except Exception as E:
            return { "exit_code":"1" ,"status": "Injector failed sending logs to db" }



    def _get_fault_info(self,fault_name):
        # Get json object for db rest api
        db_fault_api_url = "{}/{}/{}".format(self.db_api_url, "fault", fault_name)
        fault_info = requests.get(db_fault_api_url).json()

        # Get the names of the parts of the fault
        probes = fault_info["probes"]
        methods = fault_info["methods"]
        rollbacks = fault_info["rollbacks"]
        name  = fault_info["name"]

        fault_structure = {'probes' : probes , 'methods' : methods , 'rollbacks' : rollbacks}

        # fault_section can be the probes/methods/rollbacks part of the fault
        for fault_section in fault_structure.keys():
            fault_section_parts = []

            # section_part refers to a specific part of the probes/methods/rollbacks
            for section_part in fault_structure[fault_section]:
                section_part_info = requests.get("{}/{}/{}".format(self.db_api_url,fault_section,section_part)).json()
                fault_section_parts.append(section_part_info)

            fault_structure[fault_section] = fault_section_parts

        fault_structure["name"] =  name
        return fault_structure


    def _run_fault(self,dns,fault_info):
        try:

            # Gets fault parts from fault_info
            fault_name = fault_info['name']
            probes = fault_info['probes']
            methods = fault_info['methods']
            rollbacks = fault_info['rollbacks']

        except Exception as E :
            logs_object = {'name': "failed_fault" ,'exit_code' : '1' ,
                           'status' : 'expirement failed because parameters in db were missing ', 'error' : E}
            return logs_object

        try :

            method_logs = {}
            rollback_logs = {}
            probe_after_method_logs = {}

            # Run probes and get logs and final probes result
            probes_result,probe_logs  = self._run_probes(probes,dns)

            # If probes all passed continue
            if probes_result is True :

                probe_logs['exit_code']  =  "0"
                probe_logs['status'] = "Probes checked on victim server successfully"

                # Run methods and  get logs and how much time to wait until checking self recovery
                methods_wait_time, method_logs = self._run_methods(methods, dns)

                # Wait the expected recovery wait time
                sleep(methods_wait_time)

                probes_result, probe_after_method_logs = self._run_probes(probes, dns)
                # Check if server self healed after injection
                if probes_result is True:
                    probe_after_method_logs['exit_code'] = "0"
                    probe_after_method_logs['status'] = "victim succsessfully self healed after injection"
                else:
                    probe_after_method_logs['exit_code'] = "1"
                    probe_after_method_logs['status'] = "victim failed self healing after injection"

                    # If server didnt self heal run rollbacks
                    for rollback in rollbacks:
                        part_name = rollback['name']
                        part_log = self._run_fault_part(rollback, dns)
                        rollback_logs[part_name] = part_log

                    sleep(methods_wait_time)
                    probes_result, probe_after_method_logs = self._run_probes(probes, dns)

                    # Check if server healed after rollbacks
                    if probes_result is True:
                        rollbacks['exit_code'] = "0"
                        rollbacks['status'] = "victim succsessfully  healed after rollbacks"
                    else:
                        rollbacks['exit_code'] = "1"
                        rollbacks['status'] = "victim failed healing after rollbacks"
            else :
                probe_logs['exit_code'] = "1"
                probe_logs['status'] = "Probes check failed on victim server"

            logs_object = {'name': fault_name ,'exit_code' : '0' ,
                           'status' : 'expirement ran as expected','rollbacks' : rollback_logs ,
                           'probes' : probe_logs , 'method_logs' : method_logs,
                           'probe_after_method_logs' : probe_after_method_logs}

            if logs_object["probe_after_method_logs"]["exit_code"] == "0" :
                logs_object["successful"] = True
            else:
                logs_object["successful"] = False

        except Exception as E:
            logs_object = {'name': fault_name ,'exit_code' : '1' ,
                           'status' : 'expirement failed because of an unexpected reason', 'error' : E}

        return logs_object


    def _inject_script(self,dns,script_path):
        # Run script
        proc = subprocess.Popen("python {} -dns {}".format(script_path,dns), stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
        # get output from proc turn it from binary to ascii and then remove /n if there is one
        output = proc.communicate()[0].decode('ascii').rstrip()
        return output

    def _run_fault_part(self,fault_part,dns):
        script, script_name = file_manipulator._get_script(fault_part)
        script_file_path = file_manipulator._create_script_file(script, script_name)
        logs = self._inject_script(dns, script_file_path)
        file_manipulator._remove_script_file(script_file_path)
        return logs


    def _str2bool(self,output):
        return output.lower() in ("yes", "true", "t", "1")


    def _run_probes(self,probes,dns):

        probes_output  = {}

        # Run each probe and get back True/False boolean result
        for probe in probes :
            output = self._run_fault_part(probe, dns)
            result = self._str2bool(output)
            probes_output[probe['name']] =  result

        probes_result = probes_output.values()

        # If one of the probes returned False the probes check faild
        if False in probes_result :
            return False,probes_output

        return True,probes_output



    def _get_method_wait_time(self,method):
        try:
            return  method['method_wait_time']
        except Exception as E :
            return 0


    def _get_current_time(self):
        current_time =  time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
        return current_time


    def _run_methods(self,methods,dns):
        method_logs = {}
        methods_wait_time = 0

        for method in methods:
            part_name = method['name']
            part_log = self._run_fault_part(method, dns)
            method_wait_time = self._get_method_wait_time(method)
            method_logs[part_name] = part_log
            methods_wait_time += method_wait_time

        return  methods_wait_time,method_logs




    def _send_result(self,dns,logs_object,collection = "logs"):
        # Get current time to timestamp the object
        current_time = self._get_current_time()


        # Creating object we will send to the db
        db_log_object = {}
        db_log_object['date'] = current_time
        db_log_object['name'] = "{}-{}".format(logs_object['name'],current_time)
        db_log_object['logs'] = logs_object
        db_log_object['successful'] = logs_object['successful']
        db_log_object['target'] = dns

        # Send POST request to db api in the logs collection
        db_api_logs_url = "{}/{}".format(self.db_api_url,collection)
        response = requests.post(db_api_logs_url, json = db_log_object)

        return  response.content.decode('ascii')
```

````
#script_manipulator.py

import os
import requests

def _get_script(fault_part):
    file_share_url = fault_part['path']
    script_name = fault_part['name']
    script = requests.get(file_share_url).content.decode('ascii')
    return script, script_name


def _create_script_file(script, script_name):
    injector_home_dir = "/root"
    script_file_path = '{}/{}'.format(injector_home_dir, script_name)
    with open(script_file_path, 'w') as script_file:
        script_file.write(script)
    return script_file_path

def _remove_script_file( script_file_path):
    os.remove(script_file_path)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit much to go through all at once. It would be better if you could separate out the general concept illustrated by examples as a single review, and then specific implementation of components for other reviews.

I'm afraid I can't give much feedback on the overall concept, but I will highlight some areas that stood out to me.

**Configuration**

You have hardcoded configuration scattered throughout your code. This not only makes it more difficult to update, but also makes it inflexible. There are a [range of options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49643793/what-is-the-best-method-for-setting-up-a-config-file-in-python), but it will depend on your specific preferences and needs.

```
def __init__(self,db_api_url = "http://chaos.db.openshift:5001"):
```

```
current_time =  time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

```
def _str2bool(self,output):
    return output.lower() in ("yes", "true", "t", "1")
```

**Path manipulation**

Don't do it manually! Trying to use string manipulation to concatenate file paths is [full of pitfalls](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f). Instead, you should use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) standard library which removes all the headaches of worrying about getting the correct separator characters etc.

You should also not hard code configuration into your functions, at least provide a means of overriding it. For example your `_create_script_file` function:

```
def _create_script_file(script, script_name):
    injector_home_dir = "/root"
    script_file_path = '{}/{}'.format(injector_home_dir, script_name)
    with open(script_file_path, 'w') as script_file:
        script_file.write(script)
    return script_file_path
```

Could be rewritten:

```
def _create_script_file(script, script_name, injector_home_dir = "/root"):
    script_file_path = Path(injector_home_dir).joinpath(injector_home_dir, script_name)
    with open(script_file_path, 'w') as script_file:
        script_file.write(script)
    return script_file_path
```

Even better, load your `injector_home_dir` from configuration or load as a `Path` object in an initializer or somewhere.

**String literals**

This may be more of a personal preference, but I think [fstrings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) are far more readable than string formatting:

```
db_fault_api_url = "{}/{}/{}".format(self.db_api_url, "fault", fault_name)
```

vs

```
db_fault_api_url = f"{self.db_api_url}/fault/{fault_name}")
```

**List/dictionary comprehension**

In this section you appear to be essentially filtering a dictionary. This can be greatly simplified since you're reusing the keys:

```
        # Get the names of the parts of the fault
        probes = fault_info["probes"]
        methods = fault_info["methods"]
        rollbacks = fault_info["rollbacks"]
        name  = fault_info["name"]

        fault_structure = {'probes' : probes , 'methods' : methods , 'rollbacks' : rollbacks}
```

```
        # Get the names of the parts of the fault
        parts = ["probes", "methods", "rollbacks", "name"]
        fault_structure = {key: value for key, value in fault_info.items() if key in parts}
```

The keys used in `parts` appear to be reused in various places so they are a good candidate for storing in configuration.

**Exception handling**

I'm not keen on this section. There is a lot of repeated code, I would much prefer to return a value based on the exception. You also have what is essentially a [bare exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except) where you catch any type of exception.

```
    def _orchestrate_injection(self,dns,fault_name):
        try :
            # Gets fault full information from db
            fault_info = self._get_fault_info(fault_name)
        except Exception as E :
            return { "exit_code":"1" ,"status": "Injector failed gathering facts" }
        try :
            # Runs the probes,methods and rollbacks by order.
            logs_object = self._run_fault(dns, fault_info)
        except :
            return { "exit_code":"1" ,"status": "Injector failed injecting fault" }
        try :
            # Sends logs to db to be stored in the "logs" collection
            db_response = self._send_result(dns,logs_object,"logs")
            return db_response
        except Exception as E:
            return { "exit_code":"1" ,"status": "Injector failed sending logs to db" }
```

Use a single try/catch block, store the response and then finally return at the end:

```
    def _orchestrate_injection(self,dns,fault_name):
        try :
            # Gets fault full information from db
            fault_info = self._get_fault_info(fault_name)
            # Runs the probes,methods and rollbacks by order.
            logs_object = self._run_fault(dns, fault_info)
            # Sends logs to db to be stored in the "logs" collection
            db_response = self._send_result(dns,logs_object,"logs")
        except SpecificExceptionType as E:
            # Examine exception and determine return message
            if e.args == condition:
                exception_message = ""
            else:
                exception_message = str(E)
            db_response = { "exit_code":"1" ,"status": exception_message }
        return db_response
```

**Repetition and encapsulation**

Consider where you're repeating code or large functions can be broken down into smaller, reusable parts. Your `run_fault` method is large, with a lot of branching. An obvious repetition is where you update the exit code:

```
# Check if server healed after rollbacks
if probes_result is True:
    rollbacks['exit_code'] = "0"
    rollbacks['status'] = "victim succsessfully  healed after rollbacks"
else:
    rollbacks['exit_code'] = "1"
    rollbacks['status'] = "victim failed healing after rollbacks"
```

This makes for a nice little function:

```
def update_exit_status(log, exit_code, status_message = ""):
    if not status_message:
        if exit_code:
            status_message = "victim successfully healed after rollbacks"
        else:
            status_message = "victim failed healing after rollbacks"
        
    log["exit_code"] = "1" if exit_code else "0"
    log["status"] = status_message
    return log
```

You use a lot a dictionary manipulation throughout, it could be worthwhile to make a small class to contain this information. This would have the benefit of removing the need for so many magic strings where you retrieve information by keys, instead you could use the properties of your class. You could also then contain some of the data handling logic within you class, instead of spread throughout the rest of your methods.

Comment: thats exactly what I was looking for ! do you have any more comments on the run fault function ?

Answer (score 2):

@erik-white covered a lot of good ground, but a couple of other things jumped out at me:

1. `if <x> is True:` should be written as just `if <x>:`
2. ```
         if logs_object["probe_after_method_logs"]["exit_code"] == "0" :
             logs_object["successful"] = True
         else:
             logs_object["successful"] = False
   ```

   could be better written as just:

   ```
         logs_object["successful"] = probe_after_method_logs["exit_code"] == "0"
   ```